# fetching a block of html code from a database and displaying it properly using php without messing up page

Tags: php, html, escaping

So I'm making a simple backend to a website where contents of given pages can be quickly edited.  Page contents are saved in a MySQL database and have the possibility of containing HTML tags.

On the edit page, I want the administrator to be able to view the HTML written on the page before choosing the option to edit it.  So, I want to display HTML tags and all.  How can I escape the tags in a big block of text?

Browsing around I learned about .  But it doesn't seem to work for what I'm trying to do.

For example, if I have:

```
$content = "<h1>test</h1>";
echo "<![CDATA[".$content."]]>";
```

I simply end up with

```
test]]>
```

written on the page.

Comment: `CDATA` tags are for XML.  What happens when you `htmlspecialchars($content)`?

Comment: Are you sure that the html tags where stored in database table correctly?

Comment: @YzmirRamirez: htmlspecialchars is the wrong function for his problem. It will convert chars like "<" to "&lt;" so that a browser will show the char "<" instead of interpreting it as an html tag

Comment: @YzmirRamirez, htmlspecialchars is exactly what I was needing!  Showing the chars is what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well ... i thought you want to give the administrator the possibility to view renderd html - and for that htmlspecialchars is wrong. But ok, shame on me and +1 for his comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to view the Html content on the page, escaped, don't use `htmlentities($content)` because special characters, like many UTF-8 characters, will not be displayed properly because the Html entities aren't always interpretted correctly.

If `$content` is UTF-8 then:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

...

[**htmlspecialchars()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is all you need when displaying Html to properly escape the special characters like &, ", ', <, and >.  That's it.

Make sure you match the encoding of `$content`.  I highly recommend using UTF-8 for everything.

To set the encoding in your Html Document:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</head>
```

Where `charset=ENCODING_OF_$content`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried htmlentities?

Like this:

```
echo htmlentities($content);
```